# Sum all the byte values from large files efficiently

Tags: c#, arrays, numbers, byte, task-parallel-library

I need to find the sums of all the byte values from 5+GB files. The question is about performance: when I use just usual expressions like `.Sum()`, `.Aggregate()` or `foreach`, and making all of that in `Parallel.For` loops - it does work, but I was told that there is some program 10x faster. It is mine.
(Also I am using `FileStream` instance with async mode on and `MemoryMappedFile` to read through)

```
// ... Above there is some Parallel.For loop
// ... Which is about to read file in chunks
// Prepare array to read bytes 
Byte[] chunk = new Byte[readingChunkSize];
// Create an accessor to perform it
using (var viewAccessor = memMappedFile.CreateViewAccessor(overallMemoryOffset, readingChunkSize, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read))
{
    // Loading desired data
    viewAccessor.ReadArray(
        0,
        chunk,
        0,
        Convert.ToInt32(readingChunkSize));
}
// Summing all the byte values 
Int64 sumFragment = 0;
for (Int64 i = 0; i < readingChunkSize; i++)
{
    sumFragment += chunk[i];
}
// Adding it to result
Interlocked.Add(ref bytesSum, sumFragment);
```

I guess it is something unobvious, cause adding more asyncs like `Task` only reduced performance.

Comment: Your question is not clear, are you asking about how to make this program faster as per the 10x you heard about? Also, not sure why you state that `Task ` can reduce performance. It can have any kind of effect, depends on whether you use it correctly or improperly.

Comment: i would just play with your read buffer and chunk size, and the use of memory mapped file seems iffy. How to make this faster question are not a good fit for stackoverflow

Comment: @peeyushsingh - It doesn't matter if you "use it correctly or improperly". Code can be "correct" but perform poorly and you can hack code that it is "improperly" called and be fast.

Comment: @peeyushsingh, yes, I know there is some program on .NET making it 10 times faster. I thought it is because of "as much parallel as possible", but this approach did not help.

Comment: If its in .net just decompile them and see what they are doing

Comment: @Enigmativity guess bad english is hard to understand, my only point was that Tasks do not have negative correlation with performance, as stated in the post. The performance can go both ways depending on the actual usage.

Comment: It would be great to see a [mcve] and also the `Task` version of the code too.

Answer (score 0):

You could try offloading the summing of the bytes to a consumer thread, but ultimately the speed by which you can get the sum is limited by the speed you can read the bytes from the file system. Personally I have made experiments with reading a single large file by using multiple readers running in multiple threads, and I have seen improvement no more than x2, and only when reading from my SSD. From my external disk, it is actually faster to read with a single reader. I haven't used `MemoryMappedFile`, only `stream.Read`.